# Вопрос по постройке класса

Tags: c#

Есть например 4 класса `TransportnoeSredstvo`, `Sobstvennik`, `FizLico`, `UyrLico`

Вот как правильно построить класс `Sobstvennik` так:

Чтобы у #1 экземпляра `TransportnoeSredstvo`, `Sobstvennik` был  `FizLico`.

А у #2 экземпляра `TransportnoeSredstvo` `Sobstvennik` был  `UyrLico`

Просто делать у `Sobstvennik` 2 свойства `FizLico` и `UyrLico`, а затем одно из них использовать, а другое оставлять null ?

Или можно как то грамотнее ?

```
class Sobstvennik
{
    public FizLico FizLico { get; set; }

    public YurLico YurLico { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Нет, там должен быть интерфейс либо абстрактный класс, который реализуют оба эти класса. Либо, если не только это отличается, то делать два разных собственника с общим предком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как же тяжело читать транслитерацию.

```
Sobstvennik = VehicleOwner
TransportnoeSredstvo = Vehicle
FizLico = Individual
UyrLico = Organisation
```

Вас спасет второй принцип ООП - наследование.

К примеру, можно создать базовый класс Client

```cs
// abstract в частности дает понять, что экземпляры этого типа создавать не следует и запрещает это делать
public abstract class Client 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Inn { get; set; }
}
```

И унаследоваться от него.

```cs
public class Individual : Client
{
    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Organisation : Client
{
    public string OfficeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда код получится такой

```cs
public class VehicleOwner
{
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

А определить реальный тип клиента можно так

```cs
if (vehicleOwner.Client is Individual individual)
{
    Console.WriteLine(individual.HomeAddress);
}
```

Либо так

```cs
switch (vehicleOwner.Client)
{
    case Individual individual:
        Console.WriteLine(individual.HomeAddress);
        break;
}
```

Это просто как пример, быть может я не до конца понял, какая именно структура данных вам нужна, но основные приниципы наследования от этого не меняются.

Comment: Понял, спасибо! А как научиться правильно проектировать классы ? Почитать паттерны проектирования ?

Comment: @Vipz надо знать основные принципы ООП и понимать, как вы эту модель будете использовать. Делать так, чтобы было удобно. Паттерны - про другое.

Comment: aepot - да вот дело в том, что принцы (инкапсуляцию, наследование, полиморфизм) понимаю, а вот как удобно строить на основе этих принципов нет xD

Comment: @Vipz вот это и поизучайте.

Comment: А адекватно вообще использовать абстрактный класс без каких либо членов, а только наследоваться для полиморфизма ? Просто в моём случае, физическое лицо и юридическое никак не пересекаются членами чтобы хоть что то объявить в абстрактном(.

Comment: @Vipz сегодня не пересекается, а завтра? Вот решите вы добавить свойство Адрес например в оба класса. Или ИНН. Или ID из базы данных. Или тот же Транспорт, решите что он должен принадлежать клиенту, а не отдельно валяться. Я не верю, что у них ничего общего нет. В конце концов поле Name может быть общее - отображаемое имя, а сама его генерация может быть в абстрактном методе, который определяется в наследнике.